# How do I build a custom video player using an image?

Tags: html, css, video

I need to embed a video onto a website but I want the video to be playing inside the empty part of this image:
[iphone_wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNcvs.png)

How do I do this? Would I place the image behind the video? Or is there a better way?

I've searched everywhere and all the tutorials show me how to make players with buttons and controls. I don't need that.

I just want to show 5 seconds clips to demo some interactions for an app I'm working on and I don't want to make gifs because the quality sucks unless I want a really slow webpage.

On Wista, I can set the video to autoplay and loop so all I really need to do is embed it inside the image.

I'm new to this so I have no idea what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

- embed
- iframe

I prefer the latter one. w3schools is a good site that can help with iframes. Just you have to set the width correctly. I can help more but I am going to need an example of your code.

Now that I think about it. You could try something like (Dont run the code snippet just expand it):

```html
<div id="frame" height="1000px" style="background-image:url(filepath from html/url);">
  <iframe src="*link to video*" style="posistion:absolute;height:1000px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Hope this is useful.